# MVC4 Ajax bouble result when submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I code web MVC4 by VS2012. I use Ajax to paging in list page, when ajax working is double result. Below is my code:

This is View:

```
<div id="result">
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Paging","pa",new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId="result"})){ %>
<table>...<table>
<div class="Paging"><%= ViewBag.PhanTrang %></div>
<%} %></div>
<script>
$(function () {
        $('.a_pt').click(function () {
            var _val = $(this).data("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: { id: _val },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#result').html(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is Controller:

```
public ActionResult Paging(string id)
{
demoMVC4Entities db = new demoMVC4Entities();
var _listProvince = db.T_Provinces;
ViewBag.ddl_Province = new SelectList(_listProvince, "Province_ID", "Province_Name");
var _listStudent = db.T_Student.OrderBy(n => n.MA).Skip((_pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
return View(_listStudent);
}
```

And this is first result:

```
<body>
<p>...</p>
<div id="result">
<form action=.............></form>
</div>
```

And this í second result:

```
<body>
<p>...</p>
<div id="result">
<form action=.............>
___<body>
___<p>...</p>
___<div id="result">
___<form action=.............></form>
___</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Plese help me.! Thanks.!

Comment: If you are using Ajax to Load a View, You should create it as a Partial View.
then from Controller use return PartialView(_listStudent)

Comment: Is this <div id="result"> in a View or a Partial View?

Comment: That is view. Can you tell me more.?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are updating the target id (#result) twice. Either remove the success function in the javascript or remove the UpdateTargetId in the Ajax Options.

hth
O

Answer (score 0):

Create a Partial View named: `WhateverList.cshtml`

Put this is in a Partial View:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Paging","pa",new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId="result"})){ %>
<table>...<table>
<div class="Paging"><%= ViewBag.PhanTrang %></div>
<%} %></div>
```

Keep this in the current view you have:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Then in Controller do this:

```
public ActionResult WhateverList(string id)
{
demoMVC4Entities db = new demoMVC4Entities();
var _listProvince = db.T_Provinces;
ViewBag.ddl_Province = new SelectList(_listProvince, "Province_ID", "Province_Name");
var _listStudent = db.T_Student.OrderBy(n => n.MA).Skip((_pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
return PartialView(_listStudent);
}
```

And you only need either the `jQUery Ajax` OR the `Ajax.BeginForm` not both:

I suggest you use jQuery in this Case:

```
<script>
$(function () {
        $('.a_pt').click(function () {
            var _val = $(this).data("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: { id: _val },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#result').html(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And remove the Ajax.BeginForm from your PartialView:

So Partial View is only:

```
@model SelectList
    <table>...<table>
    <div class="Paging"><%= ViewBag.PhanTrang %></div>
```

When you return `View()`, it will render the _Layout.cshtml of the Page , and return the `<html>, <body>` tags. But return `PartialView()` only returns the HTML content of the Partial View without `Layout.cshtml`

Comment: I did as you said but not done. I think jquery ajax have problem. Are you have skype.? give me.?

Comment: I did as you said but not done. I think jquery ajax have problem. Are you have skype? Give me?